# .container height auto not adapting to contents

Tags: css

At [this page](http://test.doig.com.au/magnifique/), in a view port of 480px in Chrome, I'd like to set:

```
#header.boxed .container {
    height: auto;
}
```

instead of:

```
#header.boxed .container {
    height: 186px;
}
```

When I do this, `#header.boxed .container` is less tall than I need it.

How do I ensure `#header.boxed .container` is tall enough to display its contents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to make some changes in 480px view-port css

```
#top .logo {
    /*background-image: url("//test.doig.com.au/magnifique/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2016/10/bg-header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 0;
}


#header #searchform {
    float: right;
    /*position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 63px;*/
    width: 220px;
}

.social_bookmarks {
    border: medium none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    /*position: absolute;
    right: 231px;*/
    top: auto;
}
```

Hope it will works for you :)

Comment: Thanks very much Maddy. I just need `#header.boxed .container { height: auto; }` or `#header.boxed { height: auto; }` to behave so that overall, the `#header.boxed` adapts to mixed view-port widths, and does not let the navigation creep up over the top of it, and the `{#top .logo img {width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;}` controls the height of `#header.boxed`.